# Reflection at a conducting surface

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electromagnetic-radiation

The boundary conditions that we used to analyse reflection and refraction at the interface between two surfaces are:

$\epsilon_1 E_1^\perp + \epsilon_2 E_2^\perp = \sigma_f$ where $\sigma_f $ is the free surface charge on the surface of the conductor. Also the other boundary condition gives:

$ (1/\mu_1)\mathbf B_1^\parallel -  (1/\mu_1)\mathbf B_1^\parallel
 = (\mathbf K_f \mathbf x\ \hat n)
$
, Here $\mathbf K_f$ is the free surface current.

My first doubt is that, in the book it says, for ohmic conductors, ($\mathbf J_f = \sigma $ **E**), there can be no free surface current since this would require an infinite electric field at the boundary. I can understand that the surface of the conductor is equipotential and thus, there can be no driving electric force on the charge on the surface thus making the surface current zero, but I didn't get what the author meant by this.

My second doubt is, in the book, it says there are no perpendicular components of electric field on both sides, thus, $\sigma_f$ = 0. How can there not be perpendicular components of electric field? Even if they were zero, if I have a conductor with some surface charge, how can it go to zero?

Comment: Can you include the exact wording used? I agree it doesn't seem to make sense. If you have any electric field at all you should have some at least bound charge on the surface and vice versa. This follows from Gauss' law if you consider a small pill box centered at the surface. The field is zero inside the conductor. If its non-zero outside the conductor then by Gauss' Law there must be some surface charge density.